# Куда вставлять ссылку на источник в Google Play?

Tags: google-play, авторские-права

У меня есть игра, в ней используется саундтрек. Этот саундтрек можно использовать в проектах, но нужно указать ссылку, автора и так далее. Где мне нужно всё это указать в на странице google play? Или вообще в самой игре?

Comment: Я бы предположил, что это должно быть в самой игре где-то около раздела "Об авторах". Но вообще-то понятия не имею.

Comment: Спасибо за предположение